# Orthonormal basis of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am trying to find an orthonormal basis of the vector space $P^{3}(t)$ with an inner product defined by

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt$$

by applying the gram schmit alogorotin to ${(1,1+t,t+t^2,t^3)}$=$(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$

Here is what I have done so far;

Suppose first we just look for an orthogonal basis, say $(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)$

Set $ w_1=v_1, ie  , w_1=1$

Then $w_2= v_2 - \lt \frac{v_2, w_1}{w_1,w_1} \gt w_1$

$$w_2= (1+t)- \frac{\int_0^1 1+t  dt}{\int_0^1 1 dt}(1)$$

$w_2=t-\frac{1}{2}$

$$w_3= (t+t^2)-\frac{\int_0^1 t+t^2 dt}{\int_0^1 1 dt}(1)-\frac{\int_0^1 t^3+t^2/2-t/2 dt}{\int_0^1(t-1/2)^2dt}(t-\frac{1}{2})$$

$w_3=(t+t^2)-\frac{5}{6}-2t+1=t^2-t+\frac{1}{6}$

$$w_4= t^3-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\int_0^1 t^4-\frac{t^3}{2} dt}{\int_0^1 (t-\frac{1}{2})^2dt}(t-\frac{1}{2})-\frac{\int_0^1 t^5-t^4+t^3/6 dt}{\int_0^1(t^2-t+1/6)^2dt}(t^2-t+1/6)$$

Which I seem to evaluate to be $t^3-3t^2/2-12t/5+39/20$

I keep seeming to get issues with finding $w_4$ though.I don't know if it just arithmetic errors or what. I get something new or huge fractions and I don't know it that would make sense. I set it up the same way as I would any of the others, but I use $v_4.$ Anyways, if someone could show me that and the normalization that'd be great. ( I know to normalize we divide just by the length of the vector). Plus, is what I have so far valid? Anything I'm missing or any tips/tricks?

Comment: Can you write down what you've got for $w_4$. Getting a huge fraction is not a hint that you are incorrect.

Comment: @John Okay, I put what I get when I do it

Comment: Did you calculate $\langle w_i, w_j\rangle$ to see if they are really zero?

Comment: @John No I haven't yet, I can, but is it worth me doing so? Could you atleast tell me if it looks right or if it is just wrong in which case I can continue to work on it?

Comment: It is just a (small) arithmetic error. The correct result for $w_4$ is $$w_4(t) = t^3 -\frac{3t^2}{2} + \frac{3t}{5} - \frac{1}{20}$$

Comment: @Winther, thanks! Other then that are the rest okay? and to normalize do i just take the length of the w by sqrt(w^2) for example and put w over that?

Comment: Everything else is OK. Yes, the ortonormal basis vectors are found from just dividing by the length: $\hat{w}_i = \frac{w_i}{\sqrt{\left<w_i,w_i\right>}}$

Comment: Ah I see, so I will take the value of <w,w> by evaluating that integral than square rooting

Comment: @Winther, but yes I still get large fractions, is it correct? for example length of $w_4$ i get sqrt(5041/2800)

Comment: I get $|w_4| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2800}} = \frac{1}{20\sqrt{7}}$. I'm guessing you have some sign-error from the squaring of $w_4$ in your calculation.

Comment: @Winther, okay I re did it and got that , thanks